# MongoDB Update Converting Date type to String Date

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm new to mongoDB and i was trying to update document in mongoDB, updated_at filed in document was getting converted from Date dataType to String post update of document.

***However same code is working with mongoDB version 4.4 but i am facing this issue in version 4.2.9 mongoDB.***

Initial document in mongoDB with filed updated_at as Type Date

[image]

Post Update document

[image]

Below java code used for updating document

```
public class RequestEntity {

    @JsonProperty(value = "_id")
    private String id;

    @JsonProperty
    @Valid
    @BsonProperty(value = "status")
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private String status;

    @JsonProperty
    @JsonSerialize(using = DateSerializer.class)
    @Valid
    @BsonProperty(value = "updated_at")
    @Getter
    private Date updatedAt;

}

// using custom DateSerializer as to tell objectMapper to serialize as DateString which mongo will understand.
public class DateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider)
            throws IOException {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
        dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5:30"));

        jsonGenerator.writeString(dateFormat.format(date));

    }
}

//Main method

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("sruDB");
        MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("test");

        String documentId = "0855:am36o0tgsd37oduy6dl7rnaj5";
        // Iterate over the query result
        Document query = new Document("_id", documentId);
        MongoCursor<Document> cursor = collection.find(query).iterator();

        // Iterate over the query result
        try {
            if (cursor.hasNext()) {
                //Fetch document
                Document document = cursor.next();
                ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
                RequestEntity requestEntity = objectMapper.convertValue(document, RequestEntity.class);
                
                //update document
                requestEntity.setStatus("initiated");
                Map<String, Object> updateRequestMap = objectMapper.convertValue(requestEntity, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
                updateRequestMap.remove("id");
                Map<String, Object> resultMap = Maps.newHashMap();
                JsonHelper.flattenMap("", updateRequestMap, resultMap);
                resultMap.values().removeIf(Objects::isNull);
                System.out.println("ResultMap :" + resultMap );
                UpdateResult updateResult = collection.updateOne(
                        Filters.eq("_id", documentId), // Filter
                        new BasicDBObject(new BasicDBObject("$set", resultMap)) // Update operation
                );
                System.out.println("Modified document count: " + updateResult.getModifiedCount());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Document with ID " + documentId + " not found.");
            }

        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }


    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: In Java you should certainly use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) for your date and time work. Skip `Date`, `DateFormat`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `TimeZone` since all of those classes have serious design problems and have been outdated the last 10 years.